# Why does my Android 4.4.2 sudden have a battery drain (Wiko Bloom)?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery

I'm currently using a Wiko Bloom, with Android 4.4.2, using the latest manufacturer update.

A few weeks ago I was trying out the Llama app and after a while I noticed that out of nowhere my battery charge would drop very suddenly to (almost nothing). If I'd see it in time, before it hit 0, then i could recharge it, but often it just depleted completely. This happens in a matter of minutes.

I thought Llama was the culprit, so I did a factory reset, but the problem still persists.

Battery stats reports about 47% phone idle, 46% mobile standby and 7% Wi-Fi.

Battery graph 1 (notice the steep sudden drop of about 45%!), and then Battery graph 2 (again... a steep drop):

[image: graph 1] [image: graph 2]
<sup>Screenshots: Graph 1 (left) and Graph 2 (right; click images for larger variants)</sup>

I installed GSam to try to get pinpoint on what is causing it, but since I'm not running root, I can't get a full report:

[image: GSam]
<sup>*GSam* screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

However, in my opinion, this doesn't seem very much out of the ordinary.

I wrote to Wiko and they want me to send in my phone to have it serviced. Before I do that (costs involved, not having my phone, might not be solved, etc.), I wanted to check if maybe there's a wizard here who can help me some more?

I don't have BT turned on, Wifi is on sporadically. Really the only apps I have installed and frequently use are GMail, Google Keep and Firefox.

If I need to go root to figure it out, that's fine; I'll just need help to do it (and to be able to restore it to a pristine state afterwards should it still not work).

Should I need to provide more information, don't hesitate to ask me.
In any case, thank you.

Edit (19/07/2015):
I have rooted my phone a few weeks ago and installed root version of GSam, together with Wakelock Detector. I believe these report more acurate data on what processes are running and such.
I have yet to pinpoint the exact source of the sudden drop in battery level.
[image: Graph 3] [image: GSam root] [image: WLD] [image: Rate of change] 
<sup>Screenshots: Graph 3 (from GSam), GSam root, Wakelock Detector (right-click images for larger variants)</sup>

I noticed that even after plugging in the charger, the % of battery continues to drop for another while.
[image: After charger]
<sup>Screenshots: Battery rate of change (right-click image for larger variant)</sup>

I'm still getting a very good number of days out of my battery (mostly because i'm not at all an active user), so no complaints here. But i'm beginning to wonder if the battery perhaps is being misread? That my phone thinks it has more power during the first few days, and then suddenly has to catch up when the voltage dips below a certain point. (The battery is indicated for 3.7V, 2000mAh)

Also: GSam sometimes indi
cates an active period, but without any effect on the battery. I'm wondering what this is.
[image: Active]
<sup>Screenshots: Active, but no drain (right-click image for larger variant)</sup>

I don't notice anything wrong with the radio strength.
[image: Radio strength]
<sup>Screenshots: Radio strength (right-click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: There seems to be some issue with the radio, it looks like. Is coverage a bit shaky there? The corresponding graphs show no "coverage gaps" (just average to good signal), but the "big drops" are always at the points where the "good signal" (dark green) stops. Which doesn't exactly explain the *amount* of drop in that short time when it happens. You might wish to try a [signal monitoring app](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_cellsignal#group_403) to watch out for frequent cell changes, and check with your provider & Wiko support (might be a modem firmware issue).

Comment: When I had the Llama app installed (which uses cell location polling), I did notice there are a lot of cells around my home (like 19 that got discovered). Maybe some of those are less than good. But like you say: it doesn't quite explain the amount of drop. Especially because the previous months my phone had been working great.

Comment: I've disabled 3G and I'm now getting a -69dBm/22asu signal on GPRS (as opposed to about -100dbM/11asu on HSPA). Maybe that will do anything. Maybe not. I'll see when my battery gets low again.

Comment: I could imagine frequent switches between 2g and 3g in specific locations, but that shouldn't give you an almost vertical line in those graphs. You could give [RF Signal Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hotrod.utility.rfsignaltrackereclair) a try to verify that (neither the newest nor the best rated app – but a look at the 3rd screenshot should tell you why I recommend that: it logs each cell switch, you can have that as CSV file and also watch the graph).

Comment: PS: Also watch out if that always happens around the same area. I remember a comparable case I had personally: provider had re-configured several of its cells, and the modem firmware couldn't deal with the new parameters. Manufacturer took it in, updated the radio image, problem gone. So that's something you could ask your provider for – and also try to find out whether other folks with a Wiko Bloom have the same issues (maybe you even can get hold of a second Bloom to check for yourself).

Comment: Thank you for your comments, Izzy. I will consider it all and continue monitoring my crazy battery.